# quasar display text/markdown from assets or statics folder

Tags: vue.js, webpack, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm trying to read the content of a markdown file (.md) stored in statics or assets folder of my quasar project and I have updated the quasar.conf.js file with the following change to support raw file loading after adding raw-loader to my project

```
  extendWebpack(cfg) {
    cfg.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.md$/i,
      use: "raw-loader"
    });
```

I'm trying to load the markdown, using import command from one of the .vue component script tag as below

```
import md from "~statics/help.md";
```

But when I run the project, it compiles to 100% and throws the below error

```
• Compiling:
 └── SPA ████████████████████ 100% done in ~13s



 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                     8:22:43 AM

This dependency was not found:

* ~statics/help.md in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--1-0!./node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/loader.auto-import.js?kebab!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/pages/Help.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save ~statics/help.md
```

let me know if any solution

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like quasar can't find the proper reference since I don't know your exact folder structure

Try using `../static/{filname}` and see if it works

Comment: tried all these paths, but still getting the same error